# Using @Inject with generic type

Tags: jsf-2, glassfish, cdi

I've been searching here about it, but haven't found an answer.

In my application, I've an abstract main class for my controllers, with some methods and properties. And I want to inject the DAO automatically.

```
abstract class AbstractController<E extends AbstractEntity, D extends AbstractDAO<E>> {
    
    @Inject
    private D dao;

    // getters and setters
}

abstract class AbstractDAO<E extends AbstractEntity> {
    @PersistentContext
    private EntityManager em;

    // finds returns E
}

// implemenation/usage

class CarController extends AbstractController<Car, CarDAO> {
}
```

Getting the exception:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-001407 Cannot declare an injection point with a type variable: [field] @Inject private AbstractController.dao
```

Using: Glassfish 3.1 and JSF 2.1.

Is there a workaround or alternative for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is `D` an EJB (a managed bean)?

Comment: Using EJB session managed beans (stateless or stateful), I can get a instance using InitialContext.lookup into the get method. But I want to use a injection like @Dependent. You got a better idea for me?

Comment: Guice is able to handle this kind of things.

Comment: Now, I'm using those DAOs as Stateful session bean and getting a instance by context lookup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's technically very complicated for reflection to detect the proper runtime type by a generic declaration in the source and cast to it. Weld simply don't and won't support it.

Better declare it against `AbstractDAO<E>`:

```
private AbstractDAO<E> dao;
```

You gain nothing with declaring it against `D` anyway.

Comment: Can I, via Weld, get a instance using lookup/newInstance/... by class name?

Answer (score 0):

[Weld is an implementation of the CDI specification and type variables in injection points are forbidden by the specification.](https://github.com/weld/core/pull/2910#issuecomment-1941564186)

If you don't care CDI specification,you can take look this [weld PR](https://github.com/weld/core/pull/2910).